# How to put syntax highlighting inside a blockquote in Markdown

Tags: github, markdown

I want to have a code block with syntax highlighting inside a blockquote in Markdown.

I have seen [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314122/is-there-a-way-to-put-code-blocks-in-block-quotes) related post on Stack Overflow Meta about how to do it on Stack Overflow. And apparently that works fine. It doesn't appear to be Markdown however and certainly doesn't work on GitHub.

I spent some time googling for other ideas with no luck.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [syntax highlighting](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-and-highlighting-code-blocks#syntax-highlighting) inside blockquote:

````
> Some code:
>
> ```yaml
> ---
> Foo: Bar
> Baz: Qux
> ```
````

[image: syntax highlighting in blockquote]

Answer (score 4):

The blockquote isn't really relevant here.

The [original Markdown project](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) was primarily concerned with writing prose and focused entirely on semantics. Presentation concerns, like syntax highlighting, were considered out of scope. Users were free to use other tools like CSS or JavaScript-based syntax highlighters on the generated HTML if they wished.

As people started using Markdown for more than just prose, several alternative implementations and dialects were published. Some of them added features that were missing from the original spec (like tables) and some changed existing behaviour (like fenced code blocks with `~~~` or ```` ``` ````).

Many of these new features differ between Markdown implementations. Stack Overflow's `<-- language: lang-foo -->` comments were once used routinely on SO to indicate a language that should be used for highlighting indented code blocks, but even here there's not used much anymore. SO infers language from a post's tags and that's usually enough.

On GitHub, language is simply [defined differently](https://github.github.com/gfm/#info-string). Code blocks should be fenced and

> The line with the opening code fence may optionally contain some text following the code fence; this is trimmed of leading and trailing whitespace and called the info string.
>
> …
>
> The content of a code fence is treated as literal text, not parsed as inlines. The first word of the info string is typically used to specify the language of the code sample, and rendered in the `class` attribute of the `code` tag.

This results in something like

````
```yaml
Foo: Bar
Baz: Qux
```
````

Now, back to the blockquote. Like just about everything else in Markdown, we can quote the code block by prefixing it with `>`:

````
> ```yaml
> Foo: Bar
> Baz: Qux
> ```
````

Comment: The blockquote really is relevant. Combining all this inside a blockquote is the bit that wasn't obvious to me and didn't seem to be documented and the bit I couldn't figure out.

Comment: Sure, is relevant in the sense that it might have been confusing. But it has nothing to do with the actual problem, which is that the Stack Overflow syntax in your question never does anything in GitHub-Flavored Markdown.

Comment: I think it would be a better answer, both for me and people in the archives, if it answered the specific question I asked, viz. "Is it possible (to include a code block inside a blockquote)". I couldn't find this in any docs. My assumption had been that the "fence" should be aligned against the left margin. A reference to docs would add a lot beyond what the other correct answer did.

Comment: @AlexHarvey, fair enough. I've added a closing paragraph and example to bring this back to the blockquote you originally asked about. I hope you find this version more helpful.

Comment: @AlexHarvey I understand you were confused but Chris gave the better answer here because he helped to eliminate the confusion you had. Whatever you do outside of the blockquote, just do the same thing inside a blockquote. I realize you just wanted the quite answer, but that wouldn't have helped next time you needed to do something else within a blockquote. With Chris's answer that should never be a problem again.

Comment: @Waylan, tbh, I didn't have any confusion about that at all. I've used a bazillion different flavours of Markdown before. It was all pretty obvious, when it failed to render at GitHub, that this is something that only works in SO. I put it in the question because SO's rules require us to show evidence of things we tried. Since I was down-voted anyway I see it clearly would have been better to just ask the question.

Comment: @AlexHarvey, I don't want to argue. I'm glad you got what you needed, whether it was from me or somebody else. But your question [originally showed](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55439863/3) the correct way of quoting a code block: simply prefix it with `>`. It would have worked. The problem was that your _code block_ wasn't properly specified: it was an indented code block with a SO-specific magic comment. If it had been a GitHub-style fenced block with the language name in its info string everything would have been fine. _That_ was the problem, and that's why I answered the way I did.

Comment: @Chris yes I see your point and I don’t remember writing the original question like that. I mostly just remember googling for ages, and being unable to find any example of a code block in Markdown. Yes okay. I evidently wrote all that to satisfy the requirement to show research. While obviously not GFM, it was the only example I could find. Thanks again.